# Send a set-cookie header to a redirect url in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, redirect, cookies

I am using node.js `request` module to fetch an id_token from an API. After fetching that id_token I want to send a `redirect uri` response with a `set-cookie header to the redirected url`. But I can't quite figure out how to do it.

Here is my code:

```
app.use("/nodejs-server/retrieveCode", function(req, res) {

        var clientID = 'some random string'
        var client_Secret = 'another random string'
        var code_token = clientID + ":" + client_Secret
        var buffer = new Buffer(code_token)
        var token = buffer.toString('base64')
        var rtoken = "Basic " + token;
        var headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': rtoken
        }
        var postData = {grant_type: 'authorization_code', code: req.query.code, redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000/nodejs-server/retrieveCode'} //Query string data
        var options  = {
            method: 'POST', //Specify the method
            body: postData,
            url: 'http://localhost:4000/server/token',
            json: true,
            headers: headers
        }
        request(options
        , function(error, response, body){
            if(error) {
                console.log(error);
            } else {
                //send a redirect uri and set-cookie header response

            }
        });
```

I tried using

```
res.redirect(302, "http://localhost:9000");
```

and it is able to redirect but I am not able to send the cookie with it as well

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

After lots of trials and errors and googling I was finally able to achieve my goal. In order to send a cookie with an expiry to the the redirect URL, I just added

```js
const expires = body.exp.toUTCString();
res.cookie('id_token', body.id_token, { expires });
res.redirect(302, 'http://localhost:8080');
```

Comment: Just a note, the 302 is not needed as Express has made 302 the default status code.

Comment: How would you do this without express?

Comment: If the redirect is within the same domain, you can set a cookie and perform the redirect in the same response. Did you try it for a different domain redirect?

Answer (score 1):

in express 4.16.3 , you must set

> res.cookie()

before

> res.redirect()

and it works for me, without error