# ExpressJS: When authenticating, do I store the JWT token from the backend or the frontend?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies

I am inheriting a backend Express API and a front end React app.

Currently I am using `cookie-parser` in my `POST /login` API like so:

```
    res.cookie('something', 'abc123', {
      maxAge: COOKIE_MAX_AGE
    });
```

on my front end app, there is a function for checking if an auth token exists:

```
export function isAuthCookiePresent() {
  console.log('ALL COOKIES:', cookies.get());
  return (
    cookies.get(AUTH_COOKIE_NAME) && cookies.get(AUTH_COOKIE_NAME) !== null
  );
}
```

And as expected I see `{ something: 'abc123' }` in my console logs.

However, when I try logging in  this using autodeployed branches in Vercel (https://vercel.com/), the cookie is missing.

I was under the impression that cookies were supposed to be set on the front end? But in the code the cookie is being set on the backend. And I don't see anything in the code that passes it to the front end. I thought I would find something on the front end like that would have a "upon successful login, execute `cookies.set("x-auth-token", res.body.token)`"

It's odd to me that it works locally at all. Would someone mind explaining how this works? I thought cookies were stored in the browser on the client side. But if that was true, why does cookie-parser even exist in express and why is it being used server side?

Answer (score 1):

> However, when I try logging in this using autodeployed branches in Vercel (https://vercel.com/), the cookie is missing.

This is because it appears you are setting the cookie server side, and as far as I know vercel only handles client side and will not let you use express.

---

> I was under the impression that cookies were supposed to be set on the front end? But in the code the cookie is being set on the backend. And I don't see anything in the code that passes it to the front end. I thought I would find something on the front end like that would have a "upon successful login, execute cookies.set("x-auth-token", res.body.token)"

Cookies can actually be set through headers (`Set-Cookie: <cookie-name>=<cookie-value>`), which is what express's `res.cookie` does. [MDN's article on the `Set-Cookie` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) says:

> The **`Set-Cookie`** HTTP response header is used to send a cookie from the server to the user agent, so the user agent can send it back to the server later. To send multiple cookies, multiple **`Set-Cookie`** headers should be sent in the same response.

---

> It's odd to me that it works locally at all. Would someone mind explaining how this works? I thought cookies were stored in the browser on the client side. But if that was true, why does cookie-parser even exist in express and why is it being used server side?

Cookies are, in fact, stored client-side. They are accessible through client side javascript and backend with the cookie header. The `cookie-parser` module is needed to parse the `name=value` syntax sent by the `Cookie` header ([Cookie - HTTP | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie)). It's being used server-side becuase validating cookies in the frontend can let any user give a false "true" value to your if statement that you use to validate cookies.

---

As an answer to the question: I recommend backend because JWTs have to be signed, and setting and signing them client-side will let anyone sign an arbitrary payload.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation about Vercel. So locally, given that the cookie is being set on the response using `res.cookie()`, how does the front end see it when I don't see any code on the front end for `cookie.set(foo, bar)`? What exactly is the difference between what happens locally and what happens on Vercel?

Comment: It uses HTTP headers locally (see [HTTP headers - HTTP | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers)). The browser interprets the header in the response and uses it to set a cookie. On vercel, are you using a serverless function? (Otherwise the cookie cannot be set there from the backend). Correct me if I'm wrong, but vercel won't allow you to use express, so how are you starting the server on vercel?

Comment: Oooo I think I get the Set-Cookie thing now! So I'm only using Vercel to deploy my front end development branch, and my backend server lives somewhere else in Google Cloud. I think I have to find a way to see if Set-Cookie will work on Vercel. Might be because I'm redirecting it using `res.status(http.OK).json({ redirect: redirectUrl, token })` when I should be doing something similar to this guy: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37760690/1555312